# Can I change the font size for mesh display overlays?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm using a 4k monitor, and generally keep the UI elements small, however I find the combination of colour and size make the annotation for 'edge length' on a selected edge just too small to read. I can adjust the DPI setting, but this scales everything (which I could maybe ajust back smaller again individualy).

Is there any setting just for this (or a smaller set) or attributes?

Comment: i had this question too. as far as this article is concerned you cannot change the size. which sucks because i use a HDTV and have the same problem. https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?263107-Change-font-size-of-numerics-in-3D-view